# Image upload in Nova resulting in SQL General error: 1364 Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Given the Nova class

```php
class Article extends Resource
{
    // [...]
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()
                ->sortable(),

            Image::make('Image', 'filename')
                ->disk('public')
                ->path('articles')
                ->prunable(),
        ];
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Why do I get this error when I upload an image?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'filename' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `article` (`id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (143, 2021-06-07 12:35:36, 2021-06-07 12:35:36))
```

Some images can be uploaded, others don't. It's not due to their filetype, as some .png works but other don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is misleading. The problem is the file size: when it's bigger than 3MB, it will throw this error.

I suggest to add a help message on the field itself until Laravel Nova use a clearer message, like so:

```php
Image::make('Image', 'filename')
    ->disk('public')
    ->path('teacher_images/source')
    ->prunable()
    ->help('Size: 3MB maximum')
```